# Why do I get prompted for "Data Source Credentials" when editing a SSRS report for SCCM?

Tags: sql-server, sccm, ssrs, sccm-2012

When attempting to add a dataset in Report Builder I am prompted to "Enter Data Source Credentials."

[image]

Choosing "Use the current Windows user" fails, and I don't have the password for the specified user.

- The environment is SCCM 2012.
- What permissions need to be changed so that I may access the SCCM datasource?
- What are best practices for giving users RW access to reports in SCCM/SSRS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was two-fold:

1. I exported the certificate from the primary site sever under "Personal\Certificates" the friendly name is "ConfigMgr SQL Server Identification Certificate." I then imported the certificate to my local workstation under "Trusted Root Certificate Authorities\Certificates." This allowed me to connect to SQL server when I choose "Use the current Windows user." Before I made this change I would get a certificate error when choosing this option.
2. I had the DBA enable db_datareader access explicitly for my user in SQL Server.

When creating a dataset I still was prompted for credentials but I can now select current user and create queries.

Comment: I had this same issue and found this to be the only solution as well.  Did you get this from Microsoft PSS/CSS?  I'm really curious to see why they went this direction.

Comment: Here are the references.
Certificates:http://thecmadmin.com/2013/07/22/fix-certificate-error-when-working-with-cm12-reports/
Permissions: http://www.windows-noob.com/forums/index.php?/topic/8052-where-do-i-find-my-sccm-data/